# Posicionamiento absoluto en CSS

Tags: css

Tenía entendido que el posicionamiento absoluto en CSS aplicado a un elemento hijo, hace que se posicione de manera respecto al elemento padre. Pero, haciendo pruebas en CodePen, me he encontrado esto lo cual veo que posiciona al elemento hijo red respecto del elemento body y no del elemento padre que sería el container. ¿Alguien me puede explicar por qué sucede esto? Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="red">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.red {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: En lugar de una imagen, pega tu código y así podremos probarlo y ayudarte. [ask]

Comment: Si el padre no tiene un posicionamiento relativo entonces toma el posicionamiento relativo en el arbol de descendencia. Si ningun ancestro lo tiene se posiciona respecto al body. Esto es, si por ej quieres pisicionar una imagen en cierto lugar encierrala en un div con posicion relative y la imagen con absolute

Comment: Ya añadí el código.

Comment: a la clase container agregale position: relative;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El posicionamiento absoluto se emplea para establecer de forma exacta la posición en la que se muestra la caja de un elemento.

En pocas palabras un elemento con position: absolute; está posicionado en relación con el elemento más cercano (en lugar de posicionado en relación con la ventana gráfica, como fijo).

Al elemento padre debes de ponerle el position: relative para que el elemento con position: absolute se situé sobre el padre.